# The Fricke involution and expansions at infinity

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $p$ be prime, and $f$ be a modular form for $\Gamma_0 (p)$ whose expansion at infinity has coefficients in ${\mathbb Z}\left[1/p\right]$. I'd like a down to earth proof that the same holds true for the image $g$ of $f$ under the Fricke involution. (Or failing that, a reference to a proof that doesn't use too much abstract machinery).

Comment: So just to be clear, the proof you don't like is that there's a smooth model for $\Gamma_0(p)$ over $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ and the $q$-expansion principle says that sections of $\omega^{\otimes k}$ on this model are precisely the modular forms whose $q$-expansion is in $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$, and Fricke involution can be defined over this ring so we're done?

Comment: @znt  I'd like a proof that bypasses the heavy algebraic geometric background of the proof you indicate and is more accessible to someone like me who is used to thinking of modular forms in a classical way. Maybe I could cope with Igusa, but Katz is out of my league.

Comment: Do you believe that the Fricke involution exists in characteristic $\ell$? Is that the issue? If you believe in Igusa then you can believe that there's some map $w$ that exists in characteristic $\ell$. Do you believe that if $f$ has coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}/\ell\mathbf{Z}$ then so does $w(f)$? Even for this I think I need some sort of $q$-expansion principle but I'm not entirely sure what I can assume. For me the reason this is true is that $w$ exists over $\mathbf{Z}/\ell\mathbf{Z}$ and the $q$-expansion principle.